# Is it possible to read pdf file inside rubyzip by pdf-reader?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-reader, rubyzip

Is it possible to read a `PDF` file inside a `zip` file by pdf-reader? I tried this code but it does not work.

```
require 'zip'

Zip::File.open('/path/to/zipfile') do |zip_file|
zip_file.each do |entry|
if entry.directory?
  puts "#{entry.name} is a folder!"
elsif entry.symlink?
  puts "#{entry.name} is a symlink!"
elsif entry.file?
  puts "#{entry.name} is a regular file!"

  reader = PDF::Reader.new("#{entry.name}")
  page = reader.pages.each do |page|
  puts page.text
  end
else
  puts "#{entry.name} is something unknown"
end
end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: What was the output of the above code?

Comment: That was an error,` ArgumentError (input must be an IO-like object or a filename)`.

Comment: There might be a better way but I cannot find it. So I would try `PDF::Reader.new(StringIO.new(entry.get_input_stream.read))` the issue is that `PDF::Reader` verifies a IO like object based on `:read` and `:seek` methods and `Zip::InputStream` does not define `seek`. It does however contain an unexposed instance variable `@archive_io` which is a `File` or `IO` object so You may also be able to use  `PDF::Reader.new(entry.get_input_stream.instance_variable_get(:@archive_io))` but that just feels dirty

Comment: `PDF::Reader.new(StringIO.new(entry.get_input_stream.read))` works, but the second one has an error like : `PDF::Reader::MalformedPDFError (PDF does not contain EOF marker)`

Comment: @engineersmnky do you think I will encounter some kinda error later if I use the first one? Thanks anyway , if you provide the first option as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Tjax no you are just converting the String to a `StringIO` this is core ruby so you should not experience any issue. Even if `PDF::Reader` changes the check to something like `input.kind_of(IO)` this will still pass.

Comment: Thanks a lot , as I said if you provide it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PDF::Reader` validates that the input is a "IO-like object or a filename" based on 2 criteria.

- Determines if it is "IO-like" based on the object responding to `seek` and `read`
- Determines if it is a `File` based on `File.file?`

Excerpt [Source](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader/blob/35322db643804d610b2bf42f0eeefd7edd37266a/lib/pdf/reader/object_hash.rb#L383):

```
def extract_io_from(input)
   if input.respond_to?(:seek) && input.respond_to?(:read)
     input
   elsif File.file?(input.to_s)
     StringIO.new read_as_binary(input)
   else
     raise ArgumentError, "input must be an IO-like object or a filename"
   end
 end
```

Unfortunately while `Zip::InputStream` emulates an `IO` object fairly well it does not define `seek` and therefor it does not pass the validation above. What you can do is create a new `StringIO` from the contents of the `Zip::InputStream` via

```
StringIO.new(entry.get_input_stream.read)
```

This will guarantee that `PDF::Reader` sees this as an "IO-like object" and processes it appropriately.